# Provide Data Via Named Pipe

Tags: bash, fifo

I have a few data files that provide filenames of songs in a proprietary fashion. Now I want to convert that data to m3u-files and make that available to all applications. I don't want to use something like a cronjob that generates the m3u-files as that's not as dynamic as I want it to be.

Therefore, I decided to use named pipes. My scenario looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 sjngm sjngm 33929  6. May 12:56 songstore-1.data
prw-r--r--  1 sjngm sjngm     0  6. May 18:38 songstore-1.data.m3u
-rw-rw-rw-  1 sjngm sjngm  7750  6. May 12:56 songstore-2.data
prw-r--r--  1 sjngm sjngm     0  6. May 18:38 songstore-2.data.m3u
:
```

The script to do one run for one file seems to do its job nicely:

```
#/bin/bash

file="$1"

echo "#EXTM3U"

paste -d '\n' \
  <(tail -n +4 "$file" | grep "^#DESCRIPTION" | sed -e 's/#DESCRIPTION /#EXTINF:0,/') \
  <(tail -n +4 "$file" | grep "^#SERVICE" | cut -d ':' -f 11 | sed -e 's/%3a/:/gi')
```

This is the shell-script code that in the end should be stored in `~/.xprofile`:

```
cd ~/garage/songstores
ls -1 songstore-* |
  paste - - |
  while read in pipe; do
    echo "$in..."
    while true; do
      ~/shell-scripts/convert.sh "$in" > "$pipe"
    done &
  done
```

After running this the loops show up in `ps`. When I `cat` one m3u the output appears many more times rather than just once. One songstore-file is actually empty and the output is:

```
$ cat songstore-13.data.m3u
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
#EXTM3U
$
```

The next time I execute the `cat` the number of lines is different, but always more than one. The idea is that the `cat` results in just one display of the content.

Again, the script itself works when run in a single execution on the command line. The problem must be in connection with the pipes and how I write to (or maybe read from) them.

What didn't I understand there and how do I fix it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with named pipes. Your inner loop (`while true`) will keep executing `~/shell-scripts/convert.sh "$in" > "$pipe"` for as long as `true` is `true`. Your *outer* loop could be better written `for f in songstore-*.data; do ~/shell-scripts/convert.sh "$f" "$f.m3u"; done` - there's really no need to parse the output of `ls -1` and try to cobble pairs of files together using `paste`. Beyond that, I don't understand what your script is supposed to do.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the input regarding the outer loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) I applied a sleep to the outer loop script:

```
for f in /home/sjngm/garage/songstores-*.data; do
  echo "$f..."
  while true; do
    /home/sjngm/shell-scripts/convert.sh "$f" > "$f.m3u"
    sleep 2
  done &
done
```

2) In case anyone wants to do this: it doesn't seem to work to use process substitution when already trying to write into a named pipe. Hence, the old fashioned way using temporary files helps here:

```
#/bin/bash

file="$1"
tmpFile1="/tmp/`uuidgen`"
tmpFile2="/tmp/`uuidgen`"

tail -n +4 "$file" | grep "^#DESCRIPTION" | sed -e 's/#DESCRIPTION /#EXTINF:0,/' > $tmpFile1
tail -n +4 "$file" | grep "^#SERVICE" | cut -d ':' -f 11 | sed -e 's/%3a/:/gi' > $tmpFile2

echo "#EXTM3U"
paste -d '\n' $tmpFile1 $tmpFile2

rm $tmpFile1 $tmpFile2
```